# Number of ways to place $N$ items in $K$ bins where each bin has at least $1$ item?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the combinatoric describing the number of ways to place $N$ items in $K$ bins where each bin has at least $1$ item? Is it just $N-1$ choose $K-1$?

Comment: Yes, it is; see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29).

Comment: The answer depends on whether the items (and the bins) are distinguishable or not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is there any known article for efficiently generating all the solutions to the N-1 choose K-1 partitions?

Comment: I don’t know how efficient it is, but the first thing that occurs to me is a recursive algorithm that for $i=1$ to $N-K+1$ generates the solutions with $i$ items in the last bin. (Note that because of your mentioning the expression $\binom{N-1}{K-1}$, I’ve assumed that the bins are distinguishable and the items are not.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott In my case I am trying to find the number of ways to split up a number N into three factors based on its prime factorization (e.g. 150 = 2*3*5*5)

Comment: Oh! That’s a rather different question from the one that ALEXIS and I thought that you were asking, and a harder one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know the number of nonnegative solutions to  $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_K=N$ is

$(N+K-1)!/N!(K-1)!$ If you want $x_i \geq 1$ for all i. Then we can set $x_i=y_i+1$, with $y_i \geq 0$

and count the number of nonnegative solutions to  $(y_1+1)+(y_2+1)+\cdots+(y_K+1)=N$; that is,

$y_1+y_2+\cdots+y_K=N-K$. Thus, we get  $(N-1)!/(K-1)!(N-K)!$ which is indeed N-1 choose K-1.